# jQuery product filter function

Tags: jquery, filter, hide, show

For a page I'm creating which dynamically displays product, I'm needing to create a product filter of sort. Clicking on a li element in the ul#product-filter will show/hide the appropriate div (product category).

See my HTML code:

```
<ul id="product-filter">
    <li class="cat_1">category 1</li>
    <li class="cat_2">category 2</li>
</ul>

<div id="product-display">
    <div class="cat_1">
        <img src="image1.gif">
    </div>

    <div class="cat_2">
        <img src="image2.gif">
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently my jQuery solution is:

```
$('#products-filter li[class^=cat_]').click(function() {
    $('#products-display div[class=' + $(this).attr('class') + ']').fadeToggle();
});
```

However, this only fadeToggles the selected category (product category div). The client has requested that clicking an initial category ('li') would hide all other 'product category' divs and display only the selected. Clicking another ('li') category would also show this second product div, still showing the previous selected.. etc. Re-clicking this same 'li' item would hide the category again.. etc.

A 'reset' button would also be ideal.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `$('#products-display div.' + this.className).fadeToggle();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this implements the "client requested behavior" of the first click shows only the items clicked on and subsequent clicks just toggle the clicked on items (leaving the others as they were):

```
var clickOnce = false;
$('#product-filter li').click(function() {
    if (!clickOnce) {
        $('#product-display > div').hide();
        $('#product-display .' + this.className).show();
        clickOnce = true;
    } else {
        $('#product-display .' + this.className).toggle();
    }
});​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KHeVp/

To just show the clicked on ones and hide all others (a more traditional behavior), you could use this:

```
$('#product-filter li').click(function() {
    $('#product-display > div').hide();
    $('#product-display .' + this.className).show();
});​
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Tcjam/

Or with an animation:

```
$('#product-filter li').click(function() {
    $('#product-display > div:visible').slideUp();
    $('#product-display .' + this.className).stop(true).slideDown();
});​
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ZThzA/

Comment: Thanks for your response. This looks okay. 
However there will be approx 10 categories, and they need to show multiple if desired.

Comment: @user1426265 - This code hides all non-matching categories and shows all matching ones whether there are 2 or 100.  It will work fine however many total ones there are and however many matching ones there are.  What does this not do that you want it to do?

Comment: @user1426265 - OK, I modified my answer to hopefully implement the "client requested behavior".

Comment: The top demo is perfect. Thanks very much!

Could you briefly explain: var clickOnce = false; ?

Everything else completely makes sense.
Thanks again!

Comment: @user1426265 - Your client said they wanted a different behavior on the first click, so `clickOnce` is a global variable that tells the code whether this is the first click or not.  After the first click, it is set to `true` so it always does the toggle.  Also, since it looks like you are new to StackOverflow, do you realize that if there is an answer to your question that works for you, you should click the checkmark to the left of the answer to indicate that your problem has been solved?  This gives both you and the answerer some reputation points which can earn you privileges here.